# this inside arrow functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this following class...

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    getAge = () => this.age;
};
```

I know that when class or object methods are passed to other places, they lose `this`. So when I assign `p1.getName` method to another global variable `printName`, the value of `this` inside `printName` will be `undefined` and it will give me an error because of `this.name`. (Please see the example below) This happens because the context is changed. Is my understanding correct?

```
let p1 = new Person('John', 20);
let printName = p1.getName;
console.log(printName()); // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

So what about the one with arrow function? In `Person` class, `getAge` is a class field which has an arrow function expression. When I pass `p1.getAge` to somewhere else, `this` still references the right object.

```
let printAge = p1.getAge;
console.log(printAge());  // 20
```

When I pass `p1.getAge` method to global variable called `printAge`, the context is changed. Am I right? I also know the fact that, arrow functions capture `this` from its outer lexical scope. Based on my understanding, `this` shouldn't be `p1` object.

I know how to bind object methods. But I just want to know why does `this` inside arrow function still refer to the right object? What am I missing? Or my already understandings are wrong?

Comment: "*I also know the fact that, arrow functions capture this from its outer lexical scope.*" this is correct but the next sentence contradicts it: "*Based on my understanding, this shouldn't be p1 object.*" why wouldn't it be `p1`?

Comment: Because the context is changed and ```printAge``` is in global scope. Am I right?

Comment: No, arrow functions use the `this` from the lexical context *at creation time*. Reassigning them doesn't change that. In fact, that was a design goal behind them.

Comment: your class has a method called getName when you call this method in the second code block: let printName = p1.getName; You're not calling it as a method hence it doesn't return anything. If you did  let printName = p1.getName(); it would return the value. when you do this you'll see that printAge is not a function but you're calling it with console.log(printAge()) as if it is one.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh, so I am missing the fact that 'this' is never changed when they are inside arrow functions. Thanks man.

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you want to do `let printName = p1.getName;` anyway?

Comment: Guys, I just want to know what will happen when I move object methods to other places. I am not calling methods directly from ```p1``` object.